# Enabling AAD login for existing Virtual Machines

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

I have seen that AAD login can be enabled at the time VM creation -- when we do this, I noticed that it adds an extension someething like 'AADLoginForLinux'. But for the VMs for which we don't specify AAD login at the time of creation, how do we enable it? Can we go to the extension blade and just search for 'AADLoginForLinux' extension and install it (if available for the selected OS) ? Will that make AAD login work for the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it's possible to install VM extension for the existing VM which does not enable the AAD login in the creation time.

For Linux, you can see all the support distributions and regions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad) currently. Not long below, you also can find the steps that how to install the VM extension for the existing Linux VM.

For Windows, you can find the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#using-the-azure-cloud-shell-experience-to-enable-azure-ad-login). But it seems only the Windows Server 2019 Datacenter and the Windows 10 1809 and later are supported currently. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#supported-azure-regions-and-windows-distributions).